# Why pip install dependencies already installed?

Tags: macos, pip, python-packaging, apple-silicon

I tied to install `pyarrow` on my macbook air with Apple Silicon. I currently use `python 3.9`.
I got an error when run `pip install pyarrow`.

```
(.venv) liyucheng@liyuchengdeMacBook-Air comments_generation % pip install pyarrow
Looking in indexes: https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/
Collecting pyarrow
  Using cached https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/packages/fd/b7/78115614c4b227796cc87fff907930f6ae6dd999c5000d3d6ae5c2e54582/pyarrow-2.0.0.tar.gz (58.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/bin/python3 /Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/vf/3_f3gqj973v1c64lwhx7bfjm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-0legwd08/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/ -- 'cython >= 0.29' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version<'"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"'' setuptools setuptools_scm wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (3760 lines):
  Looking in indexes: https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version < "3.7"' don't match your environment
  Collecting cython>=0.29
    Using cached https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/packages/ad/4b/9e53bcce3c959fd0db143626e573210bba07be810fe8d7296373948c4183/Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting numpy==1.16.0
    Using cached https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/packages/04/b6/d7faa70a3e3eac39f943cc6a6a64ce378259677de516bd899dd9eb8f9b32/numpy-1.16.0.zip (5.1 MB)
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/packages/34/b6/33396512781ec5c40de2e70e8a68f2d0c4d91d6cc182410788c34a00002d/setuptools-51.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.0 MB)
  Collecting setuptools_scm
    Using cached https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/packages/db/6e/2815f7c8561b088ccedc128681e64daac3d6b2e81a9918b007e244dad8b1/setuptools_scm-5.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/packages/65/63/39d04c74222770ed1589c0eaba06c05891801219272420b40311cd60c880/wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Installing collected packages: cython, numpy, setuptools, setuptools-scm, wheel
      Running setup.py install for numpy: started
      Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/vf/3_f3gqj973v1c64lwhx7bfjm0000gn/T/pip-install-3uw70ans/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/vf/3_f3gqj973v1c64lwhx7bfjm0000gn/T/pip-install-3uw70ans/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/vf/3_f3gqj973v1c64lwhx7bfjm0000gn/T/pip-record-uxtdh14v/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/vf/3_f3gqj973v1c64lwhx7bfjm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-0legwd08/overlay --compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/vf/3_f3gqj973v1c64lwhx7bfjm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-0legwd08/overlay/include/site/python3.9/numpy
           cwd: /private/var/folders/vf/3_f3gqj973v1c64lwhx7bfjm0000gn/T/pip-install-3uw70ans/numpy/
      Complete output (3736 lines):
      Running from numpy source directory.
  
      Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
      with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:
  
        - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                                 release)
        - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)
  
  
      /private/var/folders/vf/3_f3gqj973v1c64lwhx7bfjm0000gn/T/pip-install-3uw70ans/numpy/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py:476: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
        return is_string(s) and ('*' in s or '?' is s)
      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      blis_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries blis not found in ['/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries openblas not found in ['/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas not found in ['/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas not found in ['/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_blas_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      accelerate_info:
        FOUND:
          extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
          extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
          define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
  
        FOUND:
          extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
          extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
          define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
  
      /bin/sh: svnversion: command not found
      non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_lapack_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries openblas not found in ['/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_clapack_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in /Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
        FOUND:
          extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
          extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
          define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
  
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running install
      running build
      running config_cc
      unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      build_src
      building py_modules sources
      creating build
      creating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
      creating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy
      creating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/distutils
      building library "npymath" sources
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu95', 'nag', 'absoft', 'ibm', 'intel', 'gnu', 'g95', 'pg']'
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable gfortran
      Could not locate executable f95
      customize NAGFCompiler
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      Could not locate executable f90
      Could not locate executable f77
      customize IBMFCompiler
      Could not locate executable xlf90
      Could not locate executable xlf
      customize IntelFCompiler
      Could not locate executable ifort
      Could not locate executable ifc
      customize GnuFCompiler
      Could not locate executable g77
      customize G95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable g95
      customize PGroupFCompiler
      Could not locate executable pgfortran
      don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
      C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g
  
      compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c'
      gcc: _configtest.c
      gcc _configtest.o -o _configtest
      success!
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest.o.d _configtest
      C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g
  
      compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c'
      gcc: _configtest.c
      _configtest.c:1:5: warning: incompatible redeclaration of library function 'exp' [-Wincompatible-library-redeclaration]
      int exp (void);
          ^
      _configtest.c:1:5: note: 'exp' is a builtin with type 'double (double)'
      1 warning generated.
      gcc _configtest.o -o _configtest
      success!
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest.o.d _configtest
      creating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core
      creating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src
      creating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath
      conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h
        adding 'build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath' to include_dirs.
      conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c
      conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c
      None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h']
      building library "npysort" sources
      creating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common
      conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common/npy_sort.h
        adding 'build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common' to include_dirs.
      creating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npysort
      conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npysort/quicksort.c
      conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npysort/mergesort.c
      conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npysort/heapsort.c
      conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common/npy_partition.h
      conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c
      conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common/npy_binsearch.h
      conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npysort/binsearch.c
      None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common/npy_sort.h', 'build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common/npy_partition.h', 'build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common/npy_binsearch.h']
      building extension "numpy.core._dummy" sources
      Generating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/include/numpy/config.h
      C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g
  
      compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c'
      gcc: _configtest.c
      success!
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest.o.d
      C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g
  
      compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c'
      gcc: _configtest.c
      _configtest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'endian.h' file not found
      #include <endian.h>
               ^~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g
  
      compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c'
      gcc: _configtest.c
      _configtest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'sys/endian.h' file not found
      #include <sys/endian.h>
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g
  
      compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c'
      gcc: _configtest.c
      success!
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest.o.d
      C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g
  
      compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c'
      gcc: _configtest.c
      success!
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest.o.d
      C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g
  
      compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c'
      gcc: _configtest.c
      success!
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest.o.d
      C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g
  
      compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c'
      gcc: _configtest.c
      success!
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest.o.d
      C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g
  
      compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c'
      gcc: _configtest.c
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest.o.d
      C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g
  
      compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c'
      gcc: _configtest.c
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest.o.d
      C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g
  
      compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c'
      gcc: _configtest.c
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest.o.d
      C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g
  
        ......      
                                                           ^
      12 warnings and 1 error generated.
      error: Command "gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.o.d" failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/vf/3_f3gqj973v1c64lwhx7bfjm0000gn/T/pip-install-3uw70ans/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/vf/3_f3gqj973v1c64lwhx7bfjm0000gn/T/pip-install-3uw70ans/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/vf/3_f3gqj973v1c64lwhx7bfjm0000gn/T/pip-record-uxtdh14v/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/vf/3_f3gqj973v1c64lwhx7bfjm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-0legwd08/overlay --compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/vf/3_f3gqj973v1c64lwhx7bfjm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-0legwd08/overlay/include/site/python3.9/numpy Check the logs for full command output.
  WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 20.3.3 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/bin/python3 /Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/vf/3_f3gqj973v1c64lwhx7bfjm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-0legwd08/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/ -- 'cython >= 0.29' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version<'"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"'' setuptools setuptools_scm wheel Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/liyucheng/projects/comments_generation/.venv/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I notice that the error is mainly caused by installing `numpy`. However, my virtual environment have `numpy` already installed.

I got the same error when runing `pip install --no-dependencies pyarrow`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why pip install dependencies already installed?

Looks like [*pyarrow* needs *numpy* at build time](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/f4ccceb2536bb6ed5bf584843c55c6628ad23494/python/pyproject.toml#L21-L24). Pyarrow needs to be built locally for your environment since you seem to be using Python 3.9 and there are apparently [no pre-built *wheels* of pyarrow for Python 3.9 on *PyPI*](https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/2.0.0/#files). Builds happen in *isolation*, in short: an ephemeral virtual environment is created, the build dependencies of pyarrow (which includes numpy) are installed in that environment, then pyarrow is built in that environment.

So, in conclusion, although numpy might be installed in the target environment, numpy still needs to be installed in the build environment for pyarrow.